# How to combine text with expanded variable into a variable expansion in fish

Tags: shell, fish

I need to echo the value of $bootlog1 through $bootlog5.

Something like this:

```
for n in (seq 5)
    set bootlog$n value
    echo $bootlog$n
end
```

But I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Easier to use an intermediary variable:

```
for n in (seq 5)
    set var bootlog$n
    set $var (random)
    echo $var = $$var
end
```

```
bootlog1 = 20819
bootlog2 = 19479
bootlog3 = 11254
bootlog4 = 23223
bootlog5 = 23674
```